# Filtering detail table structure query language

Tags: c#, sql-server

Query Detail Table

```
Main Table
1 .PK

Detail Table
1. PK
2. Detail description.
```

If mysql i can group the main table PK for duplicate issue but how it implement in sql server ?Since sql server required something like aggregate

E.g

```
(vehicle) Main Table 

Car 
bikes
van

(vehicleItem) Detail Table

Car->item a,item b
bikes-> item a,item c.. 
van->item b ,item c
```

I want to filter in a query  such as i want to filter item a  only?Seem quite inefficient to call in sub loop.Even put all detail item it in a column consider as incorrect but when search item id(number) might be same number unless the item id are guid and distinct different. 
** the main purpose is to output list not to sum crosstab :) ya..   grouping cool if you want to sum up.

```
var sql = "select * from vehicle ";

var command = new SqlCommand(connection,sql);
try {
 var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.HasRows) {
 while (reader.Read())
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ItemIdValue[]"])){
   var d = Request.QueryString.GetValues("ItemIdValue[]");
    if (d != null){
     if (d[0].Contains("all")){
      if (GetItemExist("  AND vehicleItem.itemId  in (SELECT itemId from item ) ")){ }
      }else{
    if (GetItemExist(" AND vehicleItem.itemId IN ( " + itemFilter.Remove(itemFilter.Length - 1) + " ) ")){ }
      }
     }
    }
   }
 }
}


At last thinking back, why not select main table and in subquery..
var sql = "select * from vehicle ";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["itemIdValue[]"])){
 var d = Request.QueryString.GetValues("itemIdValue[]");
  if (d != null){
   if (d[0].Contains("all")){
    sql = sql + @" 
    AND vehicleId IN (
     SELECT  vehicleId 
     FROM    vehicle
     JOIN    vehicleItem
     ON      vehicle.vehicleId     =   vehicleItem.vehicleId 
     WHERE   vehicleItem.itemId in 
     (SELECT itemId from item)    
                    ) ";
} else{
 for (var e = 0; e < d.Length; e++){
  itemFilter += d[e] + ",";
  _fieldVariable.Add("itemIdValue[]");
  _valueVariable.Add(d[e]);
 }
 sql = sql + @" 
 AND vehicleId IN (
  SELECT  vehicleId 
  FROM    vehicle
  JOIN    vehicleItem
  ON      vehicle.vehicleId     =   vehicleItem.vehicleId 
  WHERE   vehicleItem.itemId in ( " + itemFilter.Remove(itemFilter.Length - 1) + " )   ) ";
 }
}
        }
```

Comment: What does your mysql query look like? What have you tried on sql server?

Comment: I'm using sql server for now.. The current query combine with c# code. Currently i thinking when loop query check the item existed in second table or not..

Comment: I don't understand exactly, what you want to achive. Please edit your qestion and provide an example. Furthermore pls make clear, if your detail table contains only one record for main table's PKs or if '->' means, that there are several rows like (Car, item a), (Car, item b), ...

Comment: It's kinda simple actually.. if you doing left join. you will get 2 row but if in mysql you can group it  and eliminate the duplicate while in sql sql server i can only group upon aggregate value.I try using distinct seem not work

Comment: @Hafizan, post the CREATE TABLE statements, sample data INSERTs, and query you are having problems with.  We speak SQL here.

Comment: @DanGuzman I added some real c# code and sql what i have done.. It's not the real code but it's kind similiar..

Answer (score 0):

When joining two tables t1 and t2, a result set containing all matching rows from table t1 and table t2 is created. When you only want one resulting row per t1's row, it is up to you to filter the join accordingly.

There are several possible ways to do that:

- adapt the join's `ON` clause
- group accordingly
- specify a `WHERE` clause

As you wanted to use grouping in your request, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT m.PK, min(d.Detail) 
FROM Main m 
LEFT JOIN Detail d on d.PK=m.pk 
WHERE d.Detail = 'item a'
GROUP by m.PK
```

That way you will get one row per PK with the minimum value in detail. You can use other aggregate functions too. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx.

Edit: Added `WHERE` clause to filter by "item a".

Comment: not all thing can be aggregate like primary key.. and description ..Compare to mysql anything can be group .Want i want to knew is there is alternative way to solve this issue.For temporarly i filter via c# code and it's kinda really nasty

Comment: please edit your OP and provide what you have already done, the result of that and what you actually want